# How can i determine the fourier series of this signal

Tags: fourier-series, signal-processing

Let the following T-periodic signal:
[image]

i think that each sub-signal is $x(t) = A \cdot tri_{\frac{T}{2}}(t)$ but i dont know how to make it periodic like in each interval of length T, we get the same behavior but the triangular function is only non-zero in the interval $ -T/2 \leq t \leq T/2 $ any hints on how to approach this type problem?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. As written, to me it seems that you just want to translate the signal by $\tfrac{T}{2}$. Does this answer your question?

Comment: my question is : how to extract the fourier series of the signal in the picture @AnCar

Comment: Maybe rephrase the question you originally posted then. That function is already periodic.

Comment: Okey thank you so much i changed the title of the post @AnCar

Comment: What have you tried? The function is periodic with period $T$. Did you try to just apply the Fourier transform? Did that not work?

Comment: how can i apply the fourier transform if i dont know the literal expression of the signal explicitly? @AnCar

Comment: Oh so that is what you meant. Ok, well think of it like this. Look at one period interval, say $[0,T]$. Note that your signal is linear on in, i.e., just a line, starting from $0$ at input $0$ and ending up at height $A$ at time $T$. Therefore, your function on that interval should just be $f(t)=A\tfrac{t}{T}$.

Comment: but there is a discontinuity at 0 no? @AnCar its both 0 and A when t= T

Comment: If it is both $0$ and $A$ at a point, it is not a function, by definition. But that isn't usually a problem. The Fourier transform is defined as an operator on $L^2$, so you can ignore sets of measure zero. If you want to think of your signal as a function, you can, without loss of generality, think of the main period being $[0,T)$ and take $f(t)=A\tfrac{t}{T}$ on it. I am not sure what else you could do if all you have to go on is the graph you show.

Comment: infinite thanks @AnCar how can i give you reputation? aight imma up vote all ur replies

Comment: don't worry about it, glad if I helped.

Comment: i think you want to mean that $f(t) = A \frac{|t|}{T} $ to be exact -consider t < 0 - @AnCar

Comment: so $f(t)=A\tfrac{t}{T}$ is the definition on the main period $[0,T]$ or $[0,T)$ if you prefer to think of it like that. To extend the definition to all of $\mathbb{R}$, you would say that $f(t+kT)=A\tfrac{t}{T}$ for all integers $k$. You always move your input to $[0,T)$ to apply the definition. The absolute value is not necessary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149652/discussion-between-mohamed-salhi-and-ancar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is called sawtooth wave, appearently. In [Wikipedia’s page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave), you can find its Fourier series.

Comment: but it doesnt have a closed form, i dont want to use the floor function and no thats not what we want, because the sawtooth goes below 0 in amplitude

Comment: It has a closed form on $[0,T]$: it is simply $x(t)=A/T *t$. From that you can compute the Fourier series explicitly. I found a video that does that in detail: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_s_P5XsaKdY . I gave a short answer because this problem is well-known, and you should be able to find tons of material on that online now that you know its name.

Comment: i dont understand why he said that its an odd function meanwhile we dont have x(0) = 0 i dont understand his concept of "pseudo-odd", can you please explain?

Comment: I think he simply means that it is odd if you subtract a constant. This implies that there are only sine terms in the fourier series, and no cosine terms. What he says is not necessarily important, but I think what he writes is what you need.

Comment: ah i understand thank you so much!, can you please explain to me the terms amplitude and phase specters of a fourier series?

Comment: Amplitude is a generic term, that often refers to the maximum oscillation of a signal in one interval of periodicity. Phase spectrum… I am not sure, but it should refer to the support of the Fourier transform of the signal, or, analogously, to the indices $k$ such that the coefficients $c_k$ of the Fourier series are non-zero. Again: what he says in the video is not necessarily important, but I think what he writes on the whiteboard is what you need